# How to make div properly appear onClick?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making a site with simple JavaScript. It's supposed to show a different object when a different link is clicked. It does this but it shows the other objects which are supposed to remain hidden in the menu area, and you have to click the links a whole bunch to make it go away, and only then will the page work properly.

Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /> 
<title>Crap</title>
<body>
<script>
var current_obj='';
function showLinks(objID) {
var obj=document.getElementById(objID); if (current_obj.style) {
current_obj.style.display='none'; }
obj.style.display='block';
current_obj=obj; }
</script>
<style>
.showhide_element {
display: none; }
html {
background-image:url('dash2.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
height: 100%;
 }
#menu {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
bottom:0;
text-align:center;
background:none; 
}
.contentMenu {
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:30px;
padding-right:100px;
list-style:none;
text-decoration:none; }
.contentMenu li {
display:inline-block; 
}
.contentMenu li a {
padding:50px; 
}
#contentMenu_info {
padding: 50px 50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:110px;
color:#ffff00;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-image:url('image.png');
background-size:100% 100%;
width:400px;
height:200px;
}

#contentMenu_media {
padding: 50px 50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:110px;
color:#ffff00;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-image:url('image2.png');
background-size:100% 100%;
width:500px;
height:300px; 
}
#contentMenu_contact {
padding: 50px 50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:110px;
color:#ffff00;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background-image:url('image3.png');
background-size:100% 100%;
width:500px;
height:300px; 
}
</style>
<div id="menu">
<ul class="contentMenu">

<li><a href="#" class="contentMenu" onClick="showLinks('contentMenu_info');return false;">Info</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="contentMenu" onClick="showLinks('contentMenu_media');return false;">Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="contentMenu" onClick="showLinks('contentMenu_contact');return false;">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="contentMenu_info" class="showhide_element">

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra.
Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis.
Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

</div>
<div id="contentMenu_media" class="showhide_element">
Media stuff

</div>
<div id="contentMenu_contact" class="showhide_element"> Contact information
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gah! What did indenting ever do to you?

Comment: Someone needs to say:  "Please use some framework, like jQuery, to do this sort of style / dom manipulation.  You will save yourself hours of hair-pulling."

Comment: I think you just did say it @Steve H!  And yes, please use jQuery, indenting, and external JS/CSS files.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not exactly a pro

Comment: And I barely know JavaScript. Could somebody point me in the right direction to research how to do this? My code was working before I put the "contentMenu" in the "menu" div, that's only when stuff started getting crazy, but I needed to put the navbar at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can change these css rules

```
#contentMenu_contact {
    display: none;
}
#contentMenu_media {
    display: none;
}
```

**[edit]**
Instead of **empty** current_obj, that you hide initially, you should use object that is **actually current**, when the page is loaded, and this obj is **contentMenu_info**.

```
<script>
var current_obj = document.getElementById("contentMenu_info");
function showLinks(objID) {
    var obj=document.getElementById(objID); 
    if (current_obj.style) {
        current_obj.style.display='none'; 
    }
    obj.style.display='block';
    current_obj=obj; 
}
</script>
```

You have to either place this script at the end of the body tag or use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload)

Comment: Hey Saker, thanks very much for the reply. That works for the page when it first opens, but once I click a link it does the same thing as before. Did I screw up the JavaScript because it worked when it was simple but once I started formatting the navbar to be at the bottom it started doing this. I would like to keep the navbar at the bottom if possible

Comment: Also, it only stops doing it when I click the "Info" link btw. Does this help?

Comment: Okay so many many many hanks to SakerONE on this one, much obliged friend-- if I knew you in real life I'd buy you a drink.

So it was the display:none; that helped based on what Saker said, but I added it to the following, on top of Saker's suggestion.

    #contentMenu {
    display: none;
    }

Now the page shows nothing at start (totally acceptable) and the links work the way they're supposed to now. Again, Kudos goes to SakerONE. Thanks again dude or dudette.

Comment: Again, works amazingly, Saker, you're the best. Thank you so much.